# Given DOM Element: Trying to get XPath? (partially works)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath, domxpath

Trying to get the XPath of a Dom ***exact*** element that is clicked.

**Attempt:** I have a function called **createXPathFromElement** that takes dom element clicked on and tries to get the XPath.

**Problem with the function (as i understand it):** It gets the correct XPath unless the dom element has sibling elements with the same class name.

**What I need to do:** Consistently get the correct XPath even if:

- Selected dom element doesn't have a class and or id (or has both)
- Selected dom element may or may not have siblings (ensuring I get the correct child)
- works on any web page/site (it is for a web scraper)

To test the XPath is correct I have a function that tries to find it called `lookupElementByXPath` that takes XPath and returns the DOM element or null.

Testing Purposes: **I have a JS fiddle, as you'll see when clicked on the first 3 images I return a element - however clicking on image four and five returns null** *(this is a example html structure it could be anything!)*

*Any ideas on how to get XPath correctly for on any web page?*

```js
function createXPathFromElement(elm) {
  console.log("starting......");
  // console.log("++ elem path", elm);

  var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (var segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) {
    // console.log("parentNode ......", elm);

    if (elm.hasAttribute("id")) {
      var uniqueIdCount = 0;
      for (var n = 0; n < allNodes.length; n++) {
        if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute("id") && allNodes[n].id == elm.id)
          uniqueIdCount++;
        if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break;
      }
      if (uniqueIdCount == 1) {
        segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute("id") + '")');
        return segs.join("/");
      } else {
        segs.unshift(
          elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute("id") + '"]'
        );
      }
    } else if (elm.hasAttribute("class")) {
      // added now  - if there is a class element but has children - ensure i get the correct index of the element among children
      var hasSibling = false;
      for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) {
        if (sib.localName == elm.localName) {
          i++;
          hasSibling = true;
        }
      }
      if (hasSibling) {
        segs.unshift(
          elm.localName.toLowerCase() +
            '[@class="' +
            elm.getAttribute("class") +
            '"][' +
            i +
            "]"
        );
      }

      if (!hasSibling) {
        segs.unshift(
          elm.localName.toLowerCase() +
            '[@class="' +
            elm.getAttribute("class") +
            '"]'
        );
      }
    } else {
      for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) {
        if (sib.localName == elm.localName) {
          i++;
        }
      }
      segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + "[" + i + "]");
    }
  }

  return segs.length ? "/" + segs.join("/") : null;
}

function lookupElementByXPath(path) {
  console.log("xpath  given", path);
  var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();
  var result = evaluator.evaluate(
    path,
    document.documentElement,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null
  );

  return result.singleNodeValue;
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var srcElement = e.target;
  /* console.log("src clicked", srcElement) */
  var xpath = createXPathFromElement(srcElement);
  
  var foundElement = lookupElementByXPath(xpath)
  console.log("found element ", foundElement);
  
  
})
```

```html
<div id="featured" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="products">
        <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
                            <ul class="buttons">
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 cart" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                                <li class="haha"><a class="btn btn-2 wishlist" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 compare" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="name">
                                <h3><a>Pretty One ..</a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">$122<span>$98</span></div>
                            <div class="rating"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Now"></a>
                            <ul class="buttons">
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 cart" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 wishlist" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 compare" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="name">
                                <h3><a>Pretty Two</a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">$122<span>$98</span></div>
                            <div class="rating"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00/000000/?text=WebsiteBuilders.com"></a>
                            <ul class="buttons">
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 cart" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 wishlist" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 compare" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="name">
                                <h3><a>Pretty Three</a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">$122<span>$98</span></div>
                            <div class="rating"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end inner row -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 five-two">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net"></a>
                            <ul class="buttons">
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 cart" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 wishlist" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 compare" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="name">
                                <h3><a>Pretty Four</a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">$122<span>$98</span></div>
                            <div class="rating"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/808080/?text=Down.com"></a>
                            <div class="hot">
                                <span>HOT</span>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="buttons">
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 cart" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 wishlist" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="btn btn-2 compare" href="#"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="name">
                                <h3><a>Pretty Five</a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">$122<span>$98</span></div>
                            <div class="rating"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end inner row -->
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The usual (and more reliable) way to do this is to build up an XPath based on index positions e.g. `div[0]/div[4]/a[2]` rather than involving classes, IDs or other attributes. Everything has a positional index; only some elements have classes/IDs.